# RequireJS not loaing JavaScript in Firefox WebExtensions add-on

Tags: google-chrome-extension, requirejs, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm trying to port a Chrome Extension to a Firefox add-on using the [WebExtensions API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions). I am using [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/) to load JavaScript files.
The code below is working fine in my Chrome extension, but not in Firefox.

Anyone have any advice on this? Thanks.

*manifest.json*:

```
{
"name": "Firefox WebExtension",
"version": "0.0.5",
"manifest_version": 2,
"description": "First Firefox WebExtensions",

"icons": {
    "16": "img/c-ext3.png",
    "48": "img/c-ext3.png",
    "128": "img/c-ext3.png"
},
"background": {
    "scripts": [
        "js/vendor/require.js", "js/config/loader.js", "js/config/requireInit.js"
    ]
},
"applications": {
    "gecko": {
        "id": "abc@mozilla.org",
        "strict_min_version": "44.0",
        "strict_max_version": "50.*"
    }
},
"browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "img/c-ext3.png",
    "default_title": "Firefox WebExtension",
    "default_popup": "src/browser_action/browser_action.html"
},

"permissions": [
    "contextMenus",
    "cookies",
    "http://*/*", "https://*/*", "file://*/*",
    "notifications",
    "tabs",
    "<all_urls>"
],

"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'",


"content_scripts": [{
    "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
    "js": ["js/vendor/require.js", "js/config/loader.js", "js/config/requireInit.js"]
}],
"web_accessible_resources": [
    "js/*", "src/*", "css/*", "img/*"
]}
```

*loader.js*

```
  require.load = function(context, moduleName, url) {

  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(),
      evalResponseText = function(xhr) {
          eval(xhr.responseText);
          context.completeLoad(moduleName);

      };

  xhr.open("GET", url, true);
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function(e) {
      if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
          evalResponseText.call(window, xhr);
      }
  };
  xhr.send(null);


 };
```

*requireInit.js*:

```
var baseUrl=browser.extension.getURL("/");
requirejs.config({
    config: {
        text: {
            useXhr: function (url, protocol, hostname, port) {
                // allow cross-domain requests
                // remote server allows CORS
                return true;
            }
        }
    },
    skipDataMain: true,
    baseUrl: baseUrl,
    paths: {
        "jquery": "js/vendor/jquery",
        "underscore": "js/vendor/lodash",
        "backbone": "js/vendor/backbone",
        "marionette": "js/vendor/marionette",
        "app": "js/app"
    }
});

console.log("before loading files");//working

require(['jquery', 'app/csApp'], function ($, app) {
    console.log("all js loaded");//not working
});
```

*csApp.js*

```
console.log("inside cs app");//working
    define(function(require) {
      'use strict';
     var $ = require('jquery'),
        _ = require('underscore'),
        Backbone = require('backbone'),
        Marionette = require('marionette'),
        csApp = new Marionette.Application();

       console.log("csApp");//not working
          return csApp;
    });
```

Edit: **`console.log()` inside jQuery works. But, `console.log()` inside  *csApp.js* is not working.**

Comment: Ok so when you look at the diagnostic tools that Firefox provides and the console, what do you see there? Is there *anything* that loads at all? Some things load, and others don't? Edit your question to add these details. With the information you provide in your question one possibility is that `requireInit.js` is not executed by Firefox but this is just a guess.

Comment: Thanks for your advice @Louis  please see the edit..

Comment: You've eliminated the one possibility I expressed in my comment. Good, but you have not answered any of the questions I asked at the start of my comment. Please edit your question to answer them.

Comment: In addition to the questions already asked, please provide a *complete* [mcve] so it is possible to duplicate your issue. There are additional files which are required for your extension to function. Without those, we have to *guess* at how your extension is really configured which could have a significant impact on your problem. For the question to be on topic the code needs to be in the question. However, even a link to your code somewhere else can be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a source of the problem.

It's **[Lodash](https://lodash.com/)**.

I was using lodash.js instead of underscore.js.

```
"underscore": "js/vendor/lodash",
```

Lodash is compatible for Firefox 45-46 and I am using latest firefox i.e. 47.0 .  So i have replaced lodash with underscore and now my web extension is working fine.